# GCM new server key - What to do with old server key?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Today I implemented the new GCM flow in one of our apps which has been on the market for several years already and uses the old GCM. I must have missed when they changed it in October.

So I did all the stuff that had to be done, registered the app in the Google API console, downloaded the google-services.json and so I also generated a new server API key.

Now this new server API key works fine with the new GCM flow, but in our backend there is still the old server key which still works for the user with the currently released app.

So what do we do now? Just replace the old server key and hope the users will update the app? Or put in some condition depending on app version?

What is the best way to handle this transition?

Thx in advance :)

Comment: force to your users for update. that's the prefect way i think

Comment: And how would you do that? The old app would need to support this and it doesn't.

Comment: If you update your app then it will generate a New RegId for new version and register that in GCM server. that way your both older and newer app works.

Comment: I've changed api_key before some time. I think it's only verification that you (backend) have the right to use cloud messaging. So after the change of hash, nothing else have to change, no? Google know it's you, so he sends notifications..

Comment: I just tested it with this tool http://techzog.com/development/gcm-notification-test-tool-android/ . I used the new server API key with the old push token. I get a failure...MismatchSenderId. @MD how will the app generate a new RegId if the user doesn't update the app? Only because I update the app in the PlayStore doesn't mean the user updates as well ...